# Check access logs for specific file

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, logging

I am trying to find out how many times a specific web file has been accessed. I have root access to the server, but not sure where to look. The only place I have looked in is /home/FTPUSER/access-logs which is a sym link to /usr/local/apache/domlogs/perrysre and that access log only has 1 day of data in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which OS are we talking about? Or distro if linux

Comment: I am using CENTOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your access log contains only a day's worth of data it is presumably being rotated each day. You'll need to work out how this is configured. If you're using Linux it might be with `logrotate` -- look in `/etc/logrotate.d/` or `/etc/logrotate.conf` if they exist. On FreeBSD log rotation is configured in `/etc/newsyslog.conf`.

Apache might also be doing it via [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html). If so, this'll be set up in a `CustomLog` line in the server configuration (`httpd.conf`), which could be in `/etc/httpd` or, more likely given your log location, `/usr/local/apache/conf`.

If none of this works ask the person who configured it!

Answer (score 1):

I think, since from your question I can't argue the system settings you are operating in,
a universal way to find files used by a process can do the trick.

Try using **lsof -p `<PID_OF_APACHE_DAEMON>`**.

You can retrieve the PID in a number of ways, one can be looking at *netstat -tlnop* output,
another is using *lsof -i*, and so on.

This is a POC that can work:

```
lsof -p $(lsof -i :80 | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}') | grep log

httpd   2618 root  mem    REG  253,0           64072 /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_logio.so (path inode=63267)
httpd   2618 root  mem    REG  253,0           64070 /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so (path inode=63265)
httpd   2618 root    2w   REG  253,2    1461  720904 /var/log/httpd/error_log
httpd   2618 root    6w   REG  253,2    1461  720904 /var/log/httpd/error_log
httpd   2618 root    7w   REG  253,2    4483  720899 /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

Here I have assumed your apache daemon is listening on the standard tcp port 80 of course.

Answer (score 0):

all Apache logs are usually stored in :

/var/log/apache(2)/access.log

/var/log/apache(2)/error.log

/var/log/apache(2)/customs .log

a nice commande I like in order to count something :

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep WORD-TO-LOOK | wc -l
```

then you will have a number.
Let's suppose you have a FTP logs, and every time john connects, there is a line 'John opened a session'. So you will do :

```
cat /var/log/ftp.log | grep John opened a session | wc -l
```

will give you how many times did John open a session.
If you want period of times,etc you could also do it

Comment: Why don't grep directly the file avoiding cat?

Comment: You need to quote 'John opened a session' because it contains spaces. And "grep -c 'John opened a session' /var/log/ftp.log" avoids both cat and wc!